# Drawing app - drawing void doesnt work

Tags: c++, drawing

im making an app in Mic. Visual Studio, but i have a problem with this code. Its supposed to be a drawing app like paint. This part of the code is making the line/ drawing, i have a problem with the following:

- "Graphics g = Graphics::FromImage(iBitMapImage);" ->

Error C2664: 'System::Drawing::Graphics ^System::Drawing::Graphics::FromImage(System::Drawing::Image ^)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'System::Drawing::Image' to 'System::Drawing::Image ^'    e:\programovanie\ikid\kreslenie\testing123l\testing123l\MyForm1.h   215 1   testing123l

- "pictureBox->Image = bitmap;" ->

IntelliSense: function "System::Windows::Forms::PictureBox::Image::set" cannot be called with the given argument list
            argument types are: (System::Drawing::Bitmap)
            object type is: System::Windows::Forms::PictureBox ^    e:\Programovanie\iKID\Kreslenie\testing123l\testing123l\MyForm1.h   218 4   testing123l

Im quite new to this type of C++, until now i was doing some simple things such as cin, cout, sort, text games and similar stuff...

```
    private: System::Void pictureBox_MouseMove(System::Object^  sender, S    ystem::Windows::Forms::MouseEventArgs^  e) 
    {
    if (e->Button == System::Windows::Forms::MouseButtons::Left)
    {
        Image ^iBitMapImage;
        Graphics g = Graphics::FromImage(iBitMapImage);
        g.DrawLine(Pens::Black, oldPosition, e->Location);
        oldPosition = e->Location;
        pictureBox->Image = bitmap;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is caused by trying to create an object of type "Image". The Image class can't be instantiated because it is abstract and has methods that aren't implemented.

You can use a handle to a 'reference type': `Image^ iBitMapImage;` (note the carot). To better understand how to use the Image class check the examples on the MSDN website https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Well i added the carrot, one error is eliminated... dont you know something about the other two errors? :)

Comment: Graphics is also an abstract class, so it´s the same issue as Image - again, use a handle to a reference.  

I'm not sure about the second one but it seems like you're trying to use a Bitmap object where you should be using an Image^. Maybe you wanted to use iBitMapImage?